# Keyboard shortcuts for each input language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

Can I set up keyboard shortcuts for each input language? For example I want to set "Ctrl + 8" for English, "Ctrl + 9" for Ukrainian and "Ctrl + 0" for Russian languages. I don't want to switch and search language I need. It takes time. I want directly to turn language I want. I had this ability  in Windows. Maybe I need to install some plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **System Settings      -  Keyboard - Shortcuts**. Click on "Add" button.

(See here for how to create a custom shortcut: http://web.archive.org/web/20150705203244/http://bigknol.com/create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-for-launching-chrome-firefox/)

[image]

For the name write,for example name of the input language - "English".

For the command write

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

Here **0** indicates the number of the input language. (0 for the first one, 1 for the second one, etc.)

Then press on create a shortcut button and press the key combination you want.

Change the number according to the order of input languages.
For example write

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
```

for creating a shortcut for the second language.

Answer (score 5):

As far as **current** is deprecated for `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` in GNOME 3.2 so for Ubuntu 18.04, you can use one of the following commands:

1. For the first language:

   ```
   gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
   ```
2. For the second language:

   ```
   gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
   ```

Comment: So this is applicable only for GNOME DE? What if I use XFCE?

Comment: This really should be up-voted since the accepted answer no longer works :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME no longer allows the use of `input-sources` or accepts `Eval()` natively so you have to use the following workaround.

1. Install GNOME extension [Eval-GJS](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs) - This extension provides unrestricted Eval() dbus method for running arbitrary code in the compositor.

> ```
> https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs.git
> cd eval-gjs
> make install
> ```

2. Install gnome-shell-extension-manager

> ```
> sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
> ```

3. Logout and re-login
4. Launch gnome-shell-extension-manager and enable Eval-GJS
5. Go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts and add a custom shortcut with the following command:

> ```
> gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs --method dev.ramottamado.EvalGjs.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
> ```

Replace the index in `inputSources[0]` with the actual index of the input method you wish to change to. First layout will be `inputSources[0]`, second layout will be `inputSources[1]` and so on.

Comment: And since Ubuntu 23.04 Eval-GJS "is incompatible with the current GNOME version" :(

Comment: Ok, Eval-GJS have to up the version in manifest, to make it work with current GNOME, but for now this should work: https://github.com/fetsh-edu/eval-gjs/commit/f7ef9d363f59d7578d423081d0e393c1a4096374

Answer (score 1):

Install GNOME extension [inputmethod-shortcuts](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6066/shortcuts-to-activate-input-methods/) and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I find ironic how answers under this question summarize the long history of modeless (stateless) layout switching in Ubuntu and its complicated fate.

- The `setxkbmap` doesn't play nice with the GNOME Shell. It doesn't update the UI indicator and it breaks the usual configured layout switching shortcut.
- The `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` is deprecated and doesn't work anymore
- The `gdbus call … org.gnome.Shell.Eval …` is also deprecated due to security implications.
- There is a replacement for the `Eval`: [ramottamado/eval-gjs](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs), but it doesn't solve the security issue. In fact, it introduces them! A quote from their README:

> The extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/XXXX/eval-gjs/ was not uploaded nor maintained by me. Please refrain from installing this extension at all.

---

So, I've made my own GNOME Shell Extension and I'm sharing it with the world: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)).

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'uk', 'ru'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'uk';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "us"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can even put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts". You could have one per every language you want.