# Setting hotkeys to switch language

Tags: shortcuts, language-support

How can i set Caps Lock to set Russian language and Shift + Caps Lock to set english? Not just Ctrl + Shift to switch them.

Comment: It's quite possible to set a keyboard shortcut for specific source , but I'd recommend using something else . Caps Lock does let me run custom commands, but still sets all caps.  If you would like, i can post an answer, but with different shortcuts . Is that ok ?

Comment: Hi, Rostislav ! I posted an answer. Please tests it, let me know what you think or if you have any questions. Если нужно обьяснение на русском , дайте мне знать

Answer (score 2):

The python code below is meant to be bound to two different shortcuts. 
For example for English, bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to

```
python /path/to/script us
```

And for Russian, bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to

```
python /path/to/script ru
```

For more info on setting shortcuts, read on [Luis Alvarado's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/254442/295286)

While in reality setting input source depends on it a sources index in gsettings array, this script determines each source's index automatically and appropriately sets it

#### Script source code

```py
from gi.repository import Gio
import sys

def gsettings_get(schema,path,key):
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema,path)
    return gsettings.get_value(key)

def gsettings_set(schema,path,key,value):
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema,path)
    return gsettings.set_uint(key,value)


sources = list(gsettings_get('org.gnome.desktop.input-sources', None ,'sources' ))

index = 0
for source in sources:
    for item in source:
        if sys.argv[1] == item:
           index = sources.index(source)

gsettings_set( 'org.gnome.desktop.input-sources' , None, 'current',index )
```

Comment: Nice, but you don't really need a python script, do you? http://askubuntu.com/q/690539

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  true , one can get away simply with `gsettings` alone. In fact I posted similar answer today.  I'm just making it a bit easy for the user , `us` on one key, `ru` on the other. It makes slightly more sense than figuring out which source is which index, and setting lengthy command. Plus it's an exercise in python :) But yes, you're absolutelly right, there's no need for script per se

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson in fact this question is a duplicate, can you please VTC it ?

Comment: Seems to be closed already.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know all you can change is toggling to the next language. You can do it by clicking on the language display on the taskbar and select Text Entry Settings.

There you are presented with two options:

```
Switch to next source using:
Switch to previous source using:
```

By changing them you can toggle between languages. If you have only two languages you only need to set the first one (since the second will not add to your functionality).

In your case you can set caps lock as switch to the next source and shift+caps as switch to previous source.

If I may suggest something however it would be to only set switch to next source as shift+caps. That way when typing a document hitting caps lock will not change the language allowing you to easier switch between capital and non-capital characters. Shift+Caps will always change from Russian to English and English to Russian whenever you press it.