# Switch between two Language inputs from command-line

Tags: command-line, input-language

I know that on many Desktop Environments, Using <kbd>win</kbd> +   <kbd>Space</kbd>    one can switch between installed language inputs.

Is there a **command line way** of achieving the same ?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/690539) for some guidance.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a commandline way to switch between two languages As I don't use a DE @GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: Ah, so you don't have a desktop at all? That was important information. :) You may want to check out the answer I linked to in the previous comment. Not sure, though, if it applies to you then.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried all numbers from 1 to 10, Input is still English. btw I use xmonad - tailed window manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to help by posting an own answer using the `setxkbmap` command.

To switch to English(US):

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

To switch to Kannada:

```
setxkbmap -layout in -variant kan
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't worry, there is a quick solution**.
Open a new terminal and execute `localectl set-locale LOCALEVAR=LOCALE` to impose a new locale.
Before executing the command, replace "LOCALE" with the desired locale from the output of `localectl list-locales` and "LOCALEVAR" with any variable name from the output of `locale`.

If you want to change the keyboard input locale of the terminal use `localectl set-keymap LANGNAME`; if you want to change the keyboard input locale of the GUI use `localectl set-x11-keymap LANGNAME`. Replace "LANGNAME" with the short-name of your language.

*Explanation*: the console command `localectl` is used to change the system locale and keyboard layout settings.
The system locale if for the system services and the GUI; the keyboard settings control the keyboard layout used on the console and of the GUI.

Comment: Isn't this something different than emulating <Super>+<Space> from command line for changing the current input language?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson this will change the system input locale (second part of the answer) or the system output locale (first part): all GUI and CLI applications will use the new locale if correctly configured. Note that the user who asked the question [does not use a desktop environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/830806/switch-between-two-language-inputs-from-command-line/830829?noredirect=1#comment1265969_830806), so this is a quick way to change the output/input language globally.

Comment: Maybe you are right; this is new stuff to me. If I run `localectl list-keymaps` (in a terminal window on my desktop or in a TTY window) it returns "Couldn't find any console keymaps." `setxkbmap` OTOH changes the current layout in terminal/TTY instantly.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson it happens because you did not install any keymap. :-)  `setxkbmap` is valid *only if* the system uses the old X keyboard extension. `localectl` is more portable because it uses the native `kbd` driver and the change is immediate, but you need to correctly configure your Xorg server.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. :) As regards "valid only if the system uses the old X keyboard extension" - isn't that still standard in Ubuntu? Is it about to be changed?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson you're welcome. :-)  It is not a global standard (even if *de facto* is used by many desktop systems) and, because it is an extension, can be replaced easily in future versions of the X Server or with the advent of new system daemons. This should be a good thing to keep the system safe and allow the input from new devices. ;-)