# Ubuntu 16.04 how to select each text input language source from different key combination

Tags: input-language

Ubuntu desktop Unity 16.04
I have 3 text input sources EN,GR,NO
They are cycling through Super+Spacebar

I want to select each source from different key combination
for example 
select NO with Super+N
select EN with Super+E
select GR with Super+G

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcuts for each input language](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690539/keyboard-shortcuts-for-each-input-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the terminal command to switch the input sources, I would recommend going into "system settings> keyboard> Shortcuts" and then selecting the plus sign at the bottom. it should be right next to the minus sign. there you can enter first the name of what you want to do (documentation is great) and then in the slot below the terminal command that you want to run using a key combination. (in your case change input source). Then click save/close and it will display your keyboard shortcut and say "disabled" at which point you can click on "disabled" and enter your shortcut by pressing the desired shortcut. (in your case "Super+N" "Super+E" and "Super+G", but you will have to do a different shortcut for each input source) hope this helped!

Comment: Worked great the above. Any idea how to pass the current source to the menu bar? There, it still changes with only Super+Spacebar.

Comment: @blades: Then I suspect that you used the `setxkbmap` command. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/690539/keyboard-shortcuts-for-each-input-language

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson that was it, also fixed the ctrl+c(+v),(x) problem while at the greek language. Thanx so much