# Configure keyboard shortcuts to CapsLock and Shift + CapsLock in 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

I want to configure CapsLock to switch always to the English keyboard layout (input source), while <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> switches always to Russian [18.04]

I've been using the setup described in the title successfully on Linux Mint 15, based on Cinnamon and Ubuntu 16.04.

I just went to keyboard configuration and set up combinations for each keyboard layout (input source).

I've migrated to Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop via a clean install and discovered that I can't do the same. I was gonna use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/690573/128252) solution, but in 18.04 the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key can't be used as a hotkey:

[image: Add Custom Shortcut window]

In this dialog, the CapsLock key either does nothing or reveals the Cancel button. The Save button becomes visible only when I press a combination of a modifier and a character key.

**So how do I configure CapsLock to switch to English (regardless of how many times it's pressed) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to switch to Russian?**

PS: Note that `gnome-tweaks` is irrelevant here because it has no per-language configuration options.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thank you for your comment! Please post an answer to this question, describing the way to disable the default function of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

Comment: I tried the `CapsLock is disabled` option of `gnome-tweaks`. This results in CapsLock keypress to be captured as `0xff` in the `Add Custom Shortcut` dialog. Unfortunately, the shortcut still won't work!

Comment: Here is the solution that finally worked for me for Unbuntu 18.04 and 20.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123163/modeless-stateless-layout-language-switching-with-caps-lock-again-18-04-lts-bi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install *Gnome Tweaks*:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Run *Gnome Tweaks*: Press the Super (aka Windows) key, type `Tweaks`, press Enter.
3. Go to *Keyboard & Mouse* section in the left list.
4. Click the *Additional Layout Options* button in the main area on the right.
5. Expand the *Caps Lock Behavior* section.
6. Select *Make Caps Lock an additional Menu key*. This seems to be the only option available to expose Caps Lock as a regular, non-modifier, unused key.
7. Close both windows.

You can now use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> in hot keys – both standalone and with modifiers.

---

As for switching to a specific keyboard layout, the `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0` option is deprecated and ignored.

This command works:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gdbus call … org.gnome.Shell.Eval …` mentioned in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076828/171572) is not working anymore as of 2024.

So, I've create my own GNOME Shell Extention just for that, that shares the same principle of working via D-Bus, but doesn't rely on any other interfaces, instead, implementing the solution itself:

[Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)).

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'de', 'jp'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "de"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can even put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts".