# Getting the capslock to input foreign caracters and currency

Tags: 18.04, language-support, input-language

I am having a lot of difficulty with Bionic Beaver inputting foreign characters and currencies. In the past I could easily change the settings to use [capslock] and then o"-->Ö, the came goes with [E-]-->€. Does anyone else have trouble with this in Bionic Beaver?

[Configure keyboard shortcuts to CapsLock and Shift + CapsLock in 18.04 Bionic Beaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073893/configure-keyboard-shortcuts-to-capslock-and-shift-capslock-in-18-04-bionic-be)

[as seen in the image there is not the usual keyboard and mouse tab, the settings are also different from say 16.04 etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH6Ju.png)

Comment: you want to change input languages or only cureency symbols??

Comment: Maybe you want to install the `gnome-tweaks` package and use *Tweaks*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) and have no problem using 'foreign' characters.

Install Gnome Tweaks from the Ubuntu Software Center. Navigate to `Keyboard & Mouse` and set Compose Key as per your choice.

[image]

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028957/how-to-set-a-compose-key-in-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1) useful link on achieving this.

Having set up my right windows key to perform as the compose key, pressing <kbd>RightWin</kbd> latches then pressing keys in the sequence shown below (using shift where necessary) produces the symbol shown.

[image]

Translate Page and Reader options listed are specific to my requirements but you can see that the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> can also be used for some characters.