# How I can add and remove extra keyboard languages from terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, unity, keyboard-layout, ibus

Due to foreign languase lessons in my ubuntu 16.04LTS with unity installed, I have 3 keyboard language layouts, English, Greek and Japanese (anthy). I most often use Greek and English.

My problem is that I find having 3 languages makes me less productive, so I thought if I could via a terminal alias to set "modes" for example by typing an alias like

```
japanese_on
```

I would have all three languages available, but when I type the command (alias):

```
japanese_off
```

I will no longer be able to switch to the Japanese layout with a shortcut - instead I can switch only between Greek and English (and default to English).

As far as I know both Greek and Japanese use an IBus input method instead of Xorg option.

The main difference between this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/690539/540746) is that I want to select the **list** of **available** languages that I will be able to change via pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or similar key combination.

In other words i want to do as the following image shows:

[image: result on "japanese_on" command]

[image: result on "japanese_off" command]

Comment: I assume you use Unity's graphical applet for configuring and switching between layouts. Most likely this applet stores its settings in dconf, and most likely picks up changes to dconf made by others. Do a dump of the dconf database with and without the Japanese setting, catch the difference between the two dumps and come up with dconf commands that modify the settings to get from one state to the other or vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcuts for each input language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690539/keyboard-shortcuts-for-each-input-language)

Comment: Not it is not because I want to modify the list of available languages as a whole and not set specific keyboard shortcuts for specific language.